# Set toggleButton non-clickable

Tags: java, mysql, loops, for-loop, togglebutton

So this is my movie [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWGu5.png). There are 30 `JToggleButton`. I want it to find out which seat has been selected by checking the value in `MySQL`. If the seat not selected, they are clickable, otherwise they are  not.

```
public selectSeat(String title, String day, String time) throws Exception
{
    JPanel topPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 15));
    RectDraw rect= new RectDraw();
    rect.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,25)); 
    topPanel.add(rect);

      JToggleButton[] ButtonList = new JToggleButton[30];

        JPanel ButtonPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,15,45,25)); // row,col,hgap,vgap
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            a=i+1;
            ButtonList[i]= new JToggleButton(""+a);
            ButtonPanel.add(ButtonList[i]); 
        }
         int no= findNo(day,title,time); // get hall number
         System.out.println(no); 
         List<String> seats= checkSeat(no);  // get selected seats value
         System.out.println(seats); // [22,23]
        for(String s : seats)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<30;j++)
            {
                if(s.contains(ButtonList[j].getText()))  // if seats label with 22 and 23
                {
                    ButtonList[j].setEnabled(false); // non-clickable
                }
            }

        }
```

However, the toggle button labelling with 2,3,22 and 23 become non-clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved by using this way

```
for(String s : seats) // remove [] brackets (22,23)
            {

                String[] selected=s.split(","); // remove the comma
                for (String t: selected) 
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j<30;j++)
                    {
                        if(ButtonList[j].getText().equals(t))  // if seats label with 22 and 23
                        {
                            ButtonList[j].setEnabled(false); // non-clickable
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: No, this is overly and unnecessarily complex. A debugging nightmare.

Comment: Yes, as per my answer. A simple single for loop is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if "23" contains "2" or "3" and it does. Get rid of the *outer* for loop and instead simply check if the ArrayList *contains* the String, not if the List's String contains a substring:

```
for(int j = 0; j < ButtonList.length; j++) {
    ButtonList[j].setEnabled(!seats.contains(ButtonList[j].getText()));
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but the toggle button still clickable. I think should split the arrayList

Comment: @JohnJoe: I/we have no idea since we have no clue as to what the array list contains. I had initially assumed that it contains Strings that represent seat numbers, but I seem to have assumed incorrectly.

Comment: `System.out.println(seats); // [22,23]` The seats prints [22,23]

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is the if statement `if(s.contains(ButtonList[j].getText()))`
you are checking if your String `s` which contains the number of the Buttons you should compare if the are equal with `s.equals()`

Comment: I tried but the toggle button still clickable. I think should split the arrayList

Comment: @JohnJoe: what the hell does your ArrayList contain?? You mean it has more than just a String representation of a number? You need to improve this question then so that it in fact becomes answerable.